# DataContext.CreateDatabase - Missing Backslash

Tags: .net, database

I am using vb.net and a datacontext object to create my database, and I am getting an error back telling me that it cannot create the file:

Screenshot of the error, showing how the backslash is missing

[image: img]

The user is gumter and the path is c:\users\gumter. The database to be created is DocTest.mdf. As you will see in the screenshot, the .CreateDatabase command is trying to create the file c:\users\gumterDocTest.mdf which is not allowed. How can I ensure that the backslash is in the path, so that it properly creates it in c:\users\gumter\DocTest.mdf ? I have not found anything online yet with regard to another who had encountered this problem. What I have tried, from another post, is to use:

```
' Tried either of the two below '
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", "%USERPROFILE%\")
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", "%USERPROFILE%\\")
' Code to run the creation of the database '
' Data Source=Env154STG;initial catalog=DocTest;Integrated Security=True; '
dbdc = New DocAnalyserDataContext(ConStr)
If Not dbdc.DatabaseExists Then
  Try
    db.CreateDatabase()
  Catch ex As Exception
  
  End Try
End If
```

And while that somehow does not fail in my code, it appears that it isn't used by the DataContext object. What code will help me ensure that the backslash is present when it creates the database? Or even how can i tell the DataContext where exactly I want the database to be created?

Comment: Is ignoring exceptions really what you want to do? That rarely works out well.

Comment: I can't and I don't want to. I can't live without knowing. I need to log everything. My real code uses NLOG. Would you have any comment to give regarding the actual problem I raised? I'd appreciate that, too. Thanks! :)